# Algorithm to cover set of k-combinations of M with subsets of M

Tags: set, combinations, combinatorics

I'm working on an application for which I want to take the set C of all the possible k-combinations of elements in M (with ||M|| = m), and cover C with the sets of k-combinations of subsets N_i of M, with ||N_i|| = n < m ∀ N_i

So there are (m choose k) combinations to cover, and each set Q_i of n elements will contain (n choose k) combinations.

What I'd like is an algorithm that constructs the sets Qi such that q is minimized (i.e., as close to (m choose k) / (n choose k) as possible)

So, for example, if m=100, k=3, and n=10, I would want the smallest set of sets of 10 elements such that their respective sets of 3-combinations covered the set of (100 choose 3) 3-combinations of M.

Comment: Interesting problem. Just by curiosity, why do you wanna construct the smaller sets?

Comment: @bacchus it's actually fairly complicated to explain, but the gist is that each of the elements of M represents a boolean event, so the set of possible states within M is 2^M. if i can split M into these sets of N, ||N||= n < m s.t. k-combinations are covered and 2^n is something feasible, i can parallelize the computations and guarantee combinations of at least k. it turns out this is called the **covering design** problem in combinatorics. i'll post an explanation below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but I have written a class to handle common functions for working with the binomial coefficient, which is the type of problem that your problem falls under.  It performs the following tasks:

1. Outputs all the K-indexes in a nice format for any N choose K to a file.  The K-indexes can be substituted with more descriptive strings or letters.  This method makes solving this type of problem quite trivial.
2. Converts the K-indexes to the proper index of an entry in the sorted binomial coefficient table.  This technique is much faster than older published techniques that rely on iteration.  It does this by using a mathematical property inherent in Pascal's Triangle.  My paper talks about this.  I believe I am the first to discover and publish this technique, but I could be wrong.
3. Converts the index in a sorted binomial coefficient table to the corresponding K-indexes.
4. Uses [Mark Dominus](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) method to calculate the binomial coefficient, which is much less likely to overflow and works with larger numbers.
5. The class is written in .NET C# and provides a way to manage the objects related to the problem (if any) by using a generic list.  The constructor of this class takes a bool value called InitTable that when true will create a generic list to hold the objects to be managed.  If this value is false, then it will not create the table.  The table does not need to be created in order to perform the 4 above methods.  Accessor methods are provided to access the table.
6. There is an associated test class which shows how to use the class and its methods.  It has been extensively tested with 2 cases and there are no known bugs.

To read about this class and download the code, see [Tablizing The Binomial Coeffieicent](http://tablizingthebinomialcoeff.wordpress.com/).

It should not be hard to convert this class to the language of your choice.

From your description of the problem, it looks like you should set up one loop for N (another for K if it changes as well), and then create a binomial coefficient object (BC) for that N,K combination.  Call the unsigned long version of GetBinCoeff() with the BC object to get the total number of combinations.  Then set up another loop to go through the total number of combinations of each BC object.  Inside that loop, call the BC GetKIndexes method to get the K-Indexes for each index (i.e combination) and then do your calculation.  I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to minimize.  If my suggestion is not clear or helpful enough, try posting a more detailed example that clearly shows the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I cross-posted [this question on Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98421/how-to-cover-set-of-k-combinations-of-m-with-subsets-of-m)

It turns out that this is a well-trodden problem in combinatorics called the **covering design problem**.

There is, in general, no algorithm that guarantees a minimum, although there are algorithms that are pretty close to the minimum. You can find existing known coverings and research [here](http://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html)

Comment: +1 for posting the answer to your question when you found one.